# how to wake sleeping isc-dhclient manually

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm using isc-dhclient, we know that after cable's plugged, as lease expired and no offer is received, dhclient will go sleep, and maybe 3 or 5 mins later it will wake up by itself and discover a new lease.

But my problem is, I want to wake up dhclient manually. For example, before it starts automatically, once I sense the interface is plugged again, Im able to pull up dhclient instantly, does isc-dhclient have such fuction? Or is there any option that I can write in to dhclient.conf to have it wake up earlier?

Comment: I found out that there seems a retry timeout, which can determine the duration. So now, theres only one question————does isc-dhcp provide a function allows itself to be pulled up before wake, manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use retrytime option. specify it with a small number of seconds, like 60